# BFD Library not found

Tags: c++, c, linux, ubuntu

I'm trying to use libbfd on Ubuntu and I've installed bin utils:

```
Reading state information... Done
binutils-dev is already the newest version (2.26.1-1ubuntu1~16.04.8).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 147 not upgraded.
root@server:~/Documents/Exercicios/BinaryLoader#
```

But when I try to compile my program with

```
g++ -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 loader.cc
```

I'm getting

> loader.cc:(.text+0x4c): undefined reference to bfd_get_error

> loader.cc:(.text+0x53): undefined reference to bfd_errmsg

My loader.cc file looks like:

```
#include <bfd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "loader.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

static int load_symbols_bfd(bfd *bfd_h, Binary *bin)
{
    int ret;
    long n, nsyms, i;
    asymbol **bfd_symtab;
    Symbol *sym;

    bfd_symtab = NULL;

    n = bfd_get_symtab_upper_bound(bfd_h);
    if (n < 0) {
       fprintf(stderr, "failed to read symtab (%s)\n",
               bfd_errmsg(bfd_get_error()));
       ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: You need to link in the library. Try: `g++ -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 loader.cc -lbdf`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> g++ -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 loader.cc

You didn't tell g++ to 'link with libbfd',
so in 'link' phase, it couldn't find the functions provided by libbfd.

I guess you need `g++ -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 -lbfd loader.cc`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked fine `g++ -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 loader.cc loader_demo.cc -lbfd `